# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I receive this error when I try to add a row in MySQL from Java: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`reservas`, CONSTRAINT `reservas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`codlibro`) REFERENCES `libros` (`codigolibro`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

[image: This is my database (In Spanish)]

Java class:

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    java.util.Date fechainicioutil;
    java.util.Date fechafinalutil;
    String codsocio = txtcodsocio.getText();
    int intcodsocio = Integer.parseInt(codsocio);
    String codlibro = txtcodsocio.getText();
    int intcodlibro = Integer.parseInt(codlibro);
    fechainicioutil = fechainicio.getDate();
    fechafinalutil = fechafinal.getDate();
    java.sql.Date fechainiciosql = new java.sql.Date(fechainicioutil.getTime());
    java.sql.Date fechafinalosql = new java.sql.Date(fechafinalutil.getTime());
    
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO reservas (codsocio, codlibro, fechainicioreserva, fechadevolucion) "
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        Connection reservarlibro = new Conexion().conectar();
        PreparedStatement st = reservarlibro.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setInt(1, intcodsocio);
        st.setInt(2, intcodlibro);
        st.setDate(3, fechainiciosql);
        st.setDate(4, fechafinalosql);
        st.executeUpdate();
        
        
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
```

Help!

Comment: Please add any relevant code that you wrote; your mysql schema and any stack traces. This error means that there exist a foreign key relationship that needs to be deleted before this delete can take place.

Comment: You are trying to insert or update a row in temaslibro or socio that has no row in the table libros

Comment: @nbk no, im trying to add a row in "reservas" but I receive that error

Comment: good, add only rows where codelibro exists in libros

Comment: I do that. In "codigolibros" in the table "libros" I have the codes 1 and 12, but when I try to insert a row adding 12 (or 1) in "codigolibros" in the table "reservas", I receive the same error.